# How do I hide white image "overflow" in a smaller div

Tags: html, image, css

I have a div that changes from 350px to 250px in height once you zoom in far enough, but then the image inside this div (an actual `<img>` with 100% width, not a background) will then create whitespace under the div, pushing down the thext that is under it. I found this out by using inspect element in Chrome, as seen in the image below. I thought `overflow:hidden;` would get rid of it, but it didn't.

I also think this is related to another problem where when I press these images on phone (Chrome app), they get highlighted blue even outside the div. This blue highlight even goes over other divs and is not cut off by the edge of the div itself.

I could do some tricks with negative margins, but that would place the text behind the whitespace of the image even though it's outside the div, making the text invisible. That could also be fixed using some stuff with z-index, but that would not get rid of the problem on phone when touched.

The question is now; how do I keep the image at full width, but "cut" the part that falls outside the div so the text does not get pushed down?

[image: Whitespace under div created by image pushing down text.]

```css
.photo-box {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

.photo-box img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  min-height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition:all 0.4s;
  -o-transition:all 0.4s;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 idx">
  <img src="https://wsx.moe/boxed/boxresources/idx/idx0.png" alt="Music Collection">
</div>
<div class="photo-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 idx idtxt">
  <p>~<br>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. Otherwise, this is impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: Added the css behind it. The html was already described in the text.

Answer (score 1):

please try to give height:100%; instead of auto to image class in your css

Comment: I tried it just now, and it made the image smaller than the div when not zoomed in, creating whitespace inside the div.

Comment: try to  set the vertical-align property of the image to vertical-align: bottom; vertical-align: top; or vertical-align: middle;
   and  set the display property of the image to display:block;

Comment: That almost did the trick, I also removed min height and now it looks more promising. It did not yet remove the highlight ofcourse, but I will tinker around with that more. At least the image does not push down the text anymore. Thank you for your comments.